# python3 renderPM (?) filehandle pb (through biopython)

Tags: python, python-3.x, runtime-error, biopython, filehandle

I'd like to generate a karyotype image with biopython module Bio/Graphics/BasicChromosome.py.
Here is my code

```
import sys
import pprint # debug
from Bio.Graphics import BasicChromosome


diagram = BasicChromosome.Organism()
diagram.output_format = "pdf"

# Ok, it works
# diagram.draw( "toto.pdf", "test" )

# this one fail.
with open( "toto.pdf", 'w' ) as o_out:
    diagram.draw( o_out, "test" )
```

This script generates an empty diagram, with only the title "test" in the pdf document. At least it should, and actually it does with python2.

With python3, it fails with the following error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_emptyKaryo.py", line 16, in <module>
    diagram.draw( o_out, "test" )
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/Bio/Graphics/BasicChromosome.py", line 161, in draw
    return _write(cur_drawing, output_file, self.output_format)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/Bio/Graphics/__init__.py", line 82, in _write
    return drawmethod.drawToFile(drawing, output_file)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/reportlab/graphics/renderPDF.py", line 298, in drawToFile
    c.save()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/reportlab/pdfgen/canvas.py", line 1237, in save
    self._doc.SaveToFile(self._filename, self)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/reportlab/pdfbase/pdfdoc.py", line 222, in SaveToFile
    f.write(data)
TypeError: write() argument must be str, not bytes
```

It seems that filehandle are not supported anymore.
I don't think it is a biopython error.
Can anyone give me a clue to make it works ?

If I change the output format to png, the pdf is no longer involed, so I think it came from renderPM.py.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would either need to pass string objects to your file object which was opened in `string` mode or open your output file in [`binary`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files) mode (which is easier in this case).

```
with open("toto.pdf", 'wb') as o_out:
```

should do the trick.